# PerfMon: MSMQ monitoring by type

Tags: msmq, perfmon

I'm wanting to monitor my MSMQ and I was looking at PerfMon. It has quite a few monitors that are handy like incoming messages and outgoing messages which in turn with memory and processor usage is very handy. However I would also like to monitor/highlight/split based on the message type. Is that possible?

Or is there any other tool that you know of that could do that?
Kind regards
Sidharth

Answer (score 1):

Perfmon doesn't care about the message's contents, just whether the message exists or not.